# Does Neo4j / Gremlin execute queries twice (or more) sometimes?

Tags: apache, rest, groovy, neo4j, gremlin

I query send long running gremlin / groovy query to Neo4J via Rest and it sometimes is executed twice (or more). I made sure that it is the same query by giving the query a uniq id as a parameter here "FB9ADF2A-FB4B-42FB-884B-F31C87EE200D". I have figured out a way to prevent this my using some kind of locking mechanism, but this feels ugly.

Is this considered normal behavior, or may it be created by the Apache proxy server? Or the Neo4J itself?

```
2013-09-19 14:49:01.986+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.EmbeddedGraphDatabase]: Start  FB9ADF2A-FB4B-42FB- 884B-F31C87EE200D 2013-09-19 16:46:04    FindAllRoots
 2013-09-19 14:52:21.993+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.EmbeddedGraphDatabase]: Start  FB9ADF2A-FB4B-42FB-884B-F31C87EE200D 2013-09-19 16:46:04    FindAllRoots
```

Comment: Sounds odd to me. Are you sure you're not making the request twice?

Comment: Without any code, any answer is going to be pure speculation...

Comment: After visiting that problem again I found its source: The query I issued to Neo4j was to long running... (several minutes) in the meantime the Apache Proxy I used assumed that something was wrong and issued the same request twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query seems to be disconnected after ~ 3 minutes, which is the Jetty timeout. Your http lib may resubmit the query after it gets disconnected. I experienced the same thing with neography, as the underlying httpclient library re-submits the query when it gets disconnected for long queries.